# Get users credentials from the metadata of the uploaded files in Dropbox API

Tags: python, metadata, dropbox

I have a dropbox folder shared among many users. Using the Python Dropbox SDK, I developed a polling system that scans this folder continuously in order to process all the possible files that can be uploaded in it.

My question: is there a way to establish who uploaded what in that folder? I could not find this information in the metadata of the files.

Thanking you in advance for any help.